# Spring MVC and 406 on API REST

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to realize a REST API that returns a list of entities. I've done this before, but now I am getting a 406 error when invoking the API via browser.

Here's the code.

Service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public interface Service {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/objects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    MyObject[] getObjects();

}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@RestController
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Autowired
    private MyObjectRepository myObjectRepository;

    @Override
    @ResponseBody 
    public MyObject[] getObjects() {
        MuObject[] ms = myObjectRepository.findAll().toArray(new MyObject[40]);
        return ms;
    }
}
```

MyObject

```
@Entity
@Configurable
public class MyObject extends IdentifiableEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String name;
 /* ...*/
    protected MyObject() { }
    public MyObject(String name) {this.name = name; }
}
```

IdentifiableEntity

```
@Configurable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Entity
public abstract class IdentifiableEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version = 1;
}
```

MyObjectRepository

```
@Repository
public interface MyObjectRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyObject>,
        JpaRepository<MyObject, Long> {}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:spring/database.properties"
        order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lh.mypackage" />

    <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml" />
</beans>
```

applicationContext-persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

applicationContext-jpa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.lh.mypackage.repository" />

</beans>
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lh.mypackage.service" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
  </beans>
```

mvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    MyProject
    
        contextConfigLocation
        classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you use some tool as the inspector of chrome or mozilla to see how are you sending your request? The 406 error is an HTTP error that means `406 Not Acceptable - The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.`

Comment: Another thing... I think (not sure) you should return a String or a JSon object on the implementation of your method `getObjects()`. The error means that the response format is not acceptable.

Comment: I think the problem is not the receiving format. I'm using both a browser and a client written with HTTPClient by Apache. In both case the same error. Also, Jackson should be converting automatically to JSON behind the scene, so I should not need to return a String explicitly.

Comment: Could you check whether the getObjects() method is executed? What if you return Collection rather than array in the method?

Comment: Yes, the getObjects is executed correctly and I tried with both array and collection. Actually, if I explicitly convert to json (e.g. with GSON) and return a String, everything is working correctly. It is like Jackson is not converting automatically.